# how to solve the problem : io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Connection initialization timed out. Command timed out after 5 second(s)

Tags: java, redis

What aspects can I start from to solve this problem

Modify some things to solve this problem

Unable to connect to [:6379]: Connection initialization timed out. Command timed out after 5 second(s)
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Connection initialization timed out. Command timed out after 5 second(s)